# repeating object with different time

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have a date object with some date values what I am using  in my kendo charting library..

```
var dataF = [{
                    //"date": new Date("2014/11/26 00:00:00")
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 00:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 01:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 02:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 03:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 04:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 05:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 06:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 07:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 08:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 09:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 10:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 11:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 12:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 13:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 14:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 15:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 16:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 17:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 18:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 19:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 20:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 21:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 22:00:00")
                }, {
                    "date": new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " 23:00:00")
                }];
```

This same object having 24 hours time data as you can see hour time is increasing..

like

```
"2014/11/26 00:00:00

"2014/11/26 01:00:00


"2014/11/26 02:00:00
```

In my code I am hard coding this value. I have dateF which is having 24 object with different time..

I don't want this static json contractor..
I want to do this using looping and i want to calculate is dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function makeDates(dateSelectedPopupJson) {
   var dates = [];
   for(i = 0 ; i < 24 ; i++) {
       dates.push({
         "date" : new Date(dateSelectedPopupJson + " " + i + ":00:00")
       });
   }
   return dates;
}

var dataF = makeDates('2014/11/26');
```

Comment: probably need to pad the leading zero when `i<10`

Comment: javascript should be smart enough to parse date hour without leading 0